# How to delete authentication token when logging out with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework and react native for the front-end. I am trying to delete the authentication token when a user is logging out in the front-end. But apparently the token stil exist when the logout function is triggered. Because the token still exists in the django admin panel.

So for the logout I have this service:

```
export const logoutRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/logout/");
        await removeToken();
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

and removeToken:

```
export const removeToken = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("Token");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Renove authentication token failed :", error?.message);
    }
};
```

So when a user logs in I see that a token is created in the django admin panel. But when a user logs out in the front-end I don't see in the django admin panel that the token has been removed. But the api call for the logout works. I tested this in swagger. The token has been removed in the django admin panel.

Question: how to remove the authentication token with react native?

When I trigger the log out function in react-native. I see this message in the backend:

```
Unauthorized: /api/user/logout/
[25/May/2023 10:35:54] "GET /api/user/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

Comment: You want to remove auth token in your backend when user log out from app?

Comment: @Navitas28. Yes, that is the meaning of generating and destroying a auth token? Or I am wrong? Maybe I am wrong about this. But there is a auth token be generated when I am login in the app. So then you also have to destroy the auth token when a user logs out in the app. Or not? That is just my thinking.

Comment: Yes, you are right we should destroy the token post-logout but invalidation has to be done in the backend your native code looks fine, so more information about Django code is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly logout from the Django application, your request should include authentication token too, something **like this** (not necessarely this way, it depends on your implementation):

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/logout/", {
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `token ${token}`, // Something like this, depending on your implementation
  },
});
```

Without it, the Django application doesn't know which user to logout.

This is why you are getting the `401 Unauthorized` error.

Comment: #Emanuele Scarabattoli.Thank you. But you mean in the logoutRequest?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, yes, exactly.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, added your url to the answer.

Comment: #Emanuele Scarabattoli. Thank you!! Yes, it works now.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, super! But, please, don't update the question to include the andwer, otherwise my answer will look meaningless.